# Instruction to register an application incorrect

Tags: youtube-api

I am stuck on step 4 in this instruction https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application on registering an application.

There is nothing on the left sidebar that says "Registered apps". Is the document (dated just over a month ago) already out-of-date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it's no longer there. It seems that it has been replaced by "Credentials". You should be able to figure out the basics by just reading what it says on the page. I think google is redesigning the entire cloud console and is lagging behind on the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the code examples are outdated too? e.g. in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMhN6pCAZWo , the 2nd example using OAuth doesn't work. I get "Error: redirect_uri_mismatch" and cannot locate where in the Cloud Console to register the redirect URI ...